# OnCreate ImageButton Onclick

Tags: android, imagebutton, oncreate

I'm trying to get an `ImageButton` to create another `ImageButton` in a different layout from an `OnClick`. My logcat takes me to an error on this line, but provides no further feedback:

```
ImageButton adab = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.abbutton);
```

My code:

```
package org.iimed.www;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class Penicillins extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageButton back,addmed;
    Context abbuttonplain;

    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.penicillin);

        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        addmed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addmed);

        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        addmed.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            startActivity(new Intent(
                Penicillins.this, ImageTextListViewActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.addmed:
            RelativeLayout ll=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.sundayopen);
            LayoutParams param = new
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ImageButton adab = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.abbutton);

            ll.addView(adab,param);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for you patience.

Edit: the .xml the button is to create on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/miimedback" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pillboxm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/pillbox"
    android:src="@drawable/pillbox" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/satlid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/satlid"
        android:src="@drawable/slid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/frilid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thulid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/satlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/frilid"
        android:src="@drawable/flid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thulid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/frilid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/thulid"
        android:src="@drawable/tlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/homebutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/homebutton"
        android:src="@drawable/homebut1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/wedlid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thulid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/thulid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/wedlid"
        android:src="@drawable/wlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tuelid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wedlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tuelid"
        android:src="@drawable/tlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/monlid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tuelid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/monlid"
        android:src="@drawable/mlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/adbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/abbutton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/adbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/adbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/abbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cobutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/antibiotic_buton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bppressure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/monlid"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/adbutton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bpbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/bpbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/satlidopen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/monlid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/monlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/satlidopen"
        android:src="@drawable/satlidopen" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cobutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/satlidopen"
        android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wedlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cobutton"
        android:src="@drawable/cobutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the logcat:

```
01-06 23:35:23.725: E/AndroidRuntime(29654):    at `org.iimed.www.Penicillins.onClick(Penicillins.java:50)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `ImageButton` in code, and not try to add the same `ImageButton` reference (`R.id.abbutton`). You can't add the same View (you get a reference to same inflated object using findViewbyId). Try something like:

```
RelativeLayout ll=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.sundayopen);
LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ImageButton adab = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
// Initialise ImageButton properties like the Image here...
ll.addView(adab,param);
```

Also, as a good practice you should keep the reference to your `RelativeLayout ll` in a member variable, assign in it once (look it up using `findViewbyId`) in your `onCreate` and just use it wherever you need it, that way you save the unnecessary lookups every time you click the `R.id.addmed` ImageButton.

Comment: I see, but where does it get the new Image for the new button?

Comment: I've added this Context abbuttonplain; should the (getApplicationContext()); work now?

Comment: Try one of: `adab.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` `adab.setImageDrawable(drawable);`

Comment: What's the Exception? Be a little more descriptive.

Comment: ll.addView(adab,param);  On this line 01-07 00:01:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1187):  at org.iimed.www.Penicillins.onClick(Penicillins.java:52)

Comment: Add the whole relative stack trace, the addView failed for a reason, that is mentioned somewhere in there.

Comment: 01-07 00:01:05.439: D/ActivityManager(778): Trying to launch org.iimed.www/.Penicillins
01-07 00:01:05.449: V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(778): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/org.iimed.www/create]
01-07 00:01:06.590: E/AndroidRuntime(1187):  at org.iimed.www.Penicillins.onClick(Penicillins.java:52)

Comment: Is that relevant? that's all that is showing and only the one line is a red error.

Answer (score 0):

```
back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
addmed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addmed);
```

you are using this id's to click and getting error for this is

```
  adab = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.abbutton);
```

check id and layout proper as you have no id of abbuttonin your layout